# Java obfuscation - ProGuard/yGuard/other?

Tags: java, java-me, obfuscation, proguard, yguard

This is along similar lines as these recent questions:

[Best Java Obfuscation Application For Size Reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93290/best-java-obfuscation-application-for-size-reduction)
[Creating non-reverse-engineerable Java programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149937/creating-non-reverse-engineerable-java-programs)

However, one ends up recommending yGuard and the other ProGuard but neither mention both. I wonder if we could get a comparison of each one and hear peoples experiences from both sides of the fence. Looking at this [comparison chart](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/alternatives.html) on the ProGuard website its clearly angled towards ProGuard. But what about real-world experience of each - which one produces smaller output? which one is harder to decompile from? what Java versions are supported by each?

Personally I'm particularly interested from a J2ME point of view but please don't limit the discussion to that.

Comment: Whoever wrote the classes in JDK 1.0 do a good job of obfuscation, maybe you can hire them.

Comment: Would those be the ones that documented the J2ME APIs?

Comment: I don't know which is better. I posted one of those questions (the one that says Proguard is better) hoping to get that type of dialog going, but it never went any where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proguard is a better product; especially if you take the time to go through the settings for J2ME.

Specifically for J2ME there is a far better (commercial) product called [mBooster](http://www.innaworks.com/mBooster.html)

I've been getting around 25% improvement in size on my application *after* its been through Proguard. This is mainly to do with the better Zip compression on the Jar file and comprehensive support for class merging and preverification.

Comment: Just as a note - proguard has nothing to do with the zip compression :P

Answer (score 7):

Results for my project.

- **Obfuscation** - both fine.
- **Optimisation** - ProGuard produced 20% faster code (for the measured app bottleneck).
- **Compactness** - ProGuard about 5% smaller.
- **Configuration / Ant** - YGuard is much easier to configure.

So, I'd advise ProGuard - but configuration and ant integration could definitely be improved.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is - ProGuard is better. Output is smaller a bit. Optimizing is better and much faster.

Decompiling is simple in both cases. Well, i mean, if u know Java well and really *know* business-logic of what you're decompiling, there is no problem to get it back to sources from obfuscated classes.

So, my opinion is ProGuard is better.

Comment: For Android development I would say ProGuard.