# Obfuscation with proguard

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate the source code of a product. The code is written in java and has got lot of dependencies of a particular class on other classes. Initially i thought of obfuscating major classes. Is it feasible ? Please help me with any informational inputs.

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 1):

The main point you should consider is the efficacy of code obfuscation.

It merely makes it slightly harder to read your code. This does **not** mean it makes it impossible to read, nor impervious to penetration or hacking. Remember that eventually all code must run on your customers machine, and that code will be binary instruction codes of some sort.

Bottom line - make sure you understand *why* you want to obfuscate your code, and *what* you are accomplishing by that.

Once you made sure you're on the right track - see [Java obfuscation - ProGuard/yGuard/other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150653/java-obfuscation-proguard-yguard-other) or any other related question.