# Encrypt jar executable internally in java swing application

Tags: java, swing, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating non-reverse-engineerable Java programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149937/creating-non-reverse-engineerable-java-programs)

How to encrypt jar executable internally made in java swing application? [It must be executable without decrypting it.]

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) instead of encryption. Here's what google thinks:

- http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html
- http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

See also:

- [150653](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150653/java-obfuscation-proguard-yguard-other)
- [2242055](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242055/is-java-code-obfuscation-actually-effective-vs-decompilers)
- [149937](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149937/creating-non-reverse-engineerable-java-programs)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother trying to encrypt classes. This is doomed to be utterly uselss as some form of protection. Since at some point, the JVM needs to be fed your decrypted classes, anyone interested in taking a look at them can intercept your already decrypted classes there. See **[this Article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html)** for a detailed technical explanation how **any** class encrypting can be circumvented easily.