# How to hide the '.m' files and other files when i deploy an '.exe' file of my application in matlab

Tags: matlab, exe

I have prepared my final year project in matlab and i want to make an '.exe' and deploy it to other computers.
But the problem is that all the '.m' files have to be kept in the folder of the '.exe' file so as to run it.
I **don't** want the users to look at my source code.
Is there any way to **hide them** or **make them inaccessible** to any user other but me.

Help would be appreciated.

**Sorry for not mentioning earlier, I have a couple of '.java' and '.class' files too.**

Comment: Check out pcode http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html

Comment: Thanks..that really helped to hide my '.m' files. Sorry for not mentioning earlier, I have a couple of '.java' files too...I read that 'pcode' ignores all files other than '.m'..could you suggest a solution for that?

Comment: Regarding your java-Components: Remove the source code from the matlab search path, use on of the methods discussed here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149937/creating-non-reverse-engineerable-java-programs) to protect your .class files as good as possible and add the class files or a .jar with the class files to your search path.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is known as p-file. Take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html. these p-files obfuscate your code

Answer (score 0):

While creating the exe, MATLAB compiler allows you to specify additional helper files. You can add these additional files as helpers. Please note that these files are packaged along with your MATLAB source code which gets encrypted during deployment.

If you are using DEPLOYTOOL for compilation, look at the section titled 'Files to be packaged with application'.

If using MCC, look at -a option.