# How can I achieve java byte code encryption (against reverse engineering)

Tags: java, encryption, licensing, obfuscation, bytecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to lock compiled Java Classes to prevent decompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation)

...ideally combined with licensing?
Our product is ported from PHP to Java. With PHP, there was a great code encryption / license tool named IONCube Encoder. It encrypts the PHP source code an allows the execution only if a appropriate license is present.

Is there any equivalent for a Java application (that does not rely on a hardware dongle)?

Comment: In this context, "encryption" is really just a form of obfuscation, since the key has to be available in the code you are trying to secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [JET Excelsior](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html). That's what we've been using and it's worked pretty well for us.

Comment: Oh, good Idea, we used it once a couple of years ago - we will evaluate this.

Answer (score 2):

IONCube Encoder works by **obfuscating** your code, not encrypting it.  If you want to get the same effect, there are a number of obfuscation tools for Java, such as

- [KlassMaster](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/index.html?id=001)
- [DashO](http://www.dasho.com/products/dasho/overview)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm in doubt about what you said about IONCube. It works with a key to encrypt the source code and decrypts it using a PHP-Module an the licence as decryption key.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to have a look at the [proguard obfuscator](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you but does this achieve byte code encryption?