# Proprietary java web application

Tags: java

I want to develop a commercial web application,
I know I can develop this website using PHP and then encode/obfuscate with [zend guard php encoder](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard) and other tools. If i want to develop this website using java, is it possible to protect the source code ?

Comment: The user never sees the Java source code, they only see generated HTML, JavaScript and CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect compiled Java classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443542/how-to-protect-compiled-java-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are many java obfuscation tools out there. If you must ship/distribute or entrust your java build artifacts (ie a jar, war or ear file) to a 3rd party then you can obfuscate your code, if you wish. This makes it very difficult (but not impossible) to reverse engineer.