# How to protect or secure java code from decompiling

Tags: java

I got a small doubt here. 
While we are generating any new application we used to deliver them as jar files. Now my question is **are we able to decompile these jar files**...?
if yes **how can I avoid that**...?
Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use google first, realy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation

Comment: Also often your code isn't worthy of decompilation in the first place. You just assume that people wish to see it.

Answer (score 4):

Decompilation cannot be avoided. You can easily make the code hard to read. There are free libraries available to obfuscate the code. proguard.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

You can decompile jar files (have a look at jd-decompiler).
You can't avoid it! 
You just make it harder to read it with an obfuscator. (have a look at SandMark)

or create a programm which loads a crypted version of yours at runtime into memory.