# Matlab function and Java

Tags: java, matlab

I have function in Matlab which works perfect. I got p from m file and it works on some computers, but not on every (even I did it in 6.5 version). I simply didnt know what to do, and wrote the same program in Java. BUT, the results are not allways the same, and sometimes program dont works in Java. I cannt find the mistake in Java (I know that Matlab's function is relevant).

I have two (dependent) questions:

How to make my Matlab code safe from hacking and working on every computer?

How to use Java to protect and run my Matlab code (againg on every computer)?

Is there solution for this or what?

Answer (score 0):

> How to make my Matlab code safe from hacking and working on every
>   computer?

If by 'safe from hacking' you mean protect from decompilation of your java class(es) than have a look, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation?lq=1) or many other similar questions at stack overflow.

> How to use Java to protect and run my Matlab code (againg on every
>   computer)?

Officially you cant execute matlab from withing java, although opposite is supported. However, you can use external tools e.g. [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/). But there can be licence issues if you start doing this. So be vary of that.

Comment: 'safe from hacking' - it is matlab not java code. I said I make p code from m file, but it wont run on every computer. So, what to do else or how to make p code running everywhere?