# How to Deploy Java Swing application for windows without revealing the source code

Tags: java, windows

How to deploy Java Swing application as windows software

I have tried the following to do this

I have created jar file for my project after that created exe file using Launch4j and Advanced installer, exe file produced by both softwares are working fine but those are placing the jar file inside that exe file, My problem is any one who has that exe file can extract and view the source code by decompiling java class file. Is there any way to deploy java application without decompiling the code, Please help me

Comment: What's wrong in using jar/class file ? You are not exposing any code? Or you are afraid of someone de compiling your class file?

Comment: @SMA "...any one who has that exe file can extract and view the source code by decompiling java class file..."

Comment: Directly we are not exposing any code but, we can easily get the java source code by decompiling class file with JAD, i want my code to be abstract

Comment: better candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation