# Hide code from jar file

Tags: java

I have made a jar file for a software that I need to use. The problem is that since it is a jar file, anyone can get .class files and decompile them to get the actual java code.

Could some one please point out how to keep this java code secure. I have tried converting this jar to exe using launch4j but noticed that it just packs everything to exe. This exe can be extracted and then decompiled to get the actual java code.

I just need code to be secure, whether by converting to exe or by any other method. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation)

Comment: Consider having a "do not recompile" clause in the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Java Code obfuscator which will change the Java code without changing the actual functions.

Check [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) which does that.