# How to run exe file whereas currently running jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, exe, obfuscation

I have a spring based workflow system where the java plugins are uploaded and kept in jar format, they are referred and used by the jar file. However, I have seen that jar file is very easy to decompile and it is a security risk.

I tried obfuscation as well. I want to run exe so that it is run at byte code so it is very very hard to reverse engineer.

Comment: Alternatively: [How to lock compiled Java classes to prevent decompilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation)

Comment: @Ben from this above article, I wanted to explore the third option but cannot understand how to perform it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ProGuard`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard) as optimizer and obfuscator.

`ProGuard` also has a [maven plugin](https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin) that you can use it in the build process.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am trying to avoid ofuscation as it can be reversed easily. I am looking for a byte code level execution.

Comment: This question that obfuscation how much can help code security and preventing it from being decompiled is related to the power of obfuscator. For example look at this link https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard

Comment: This is for Android, I need it for java maven plugins. Thanks though.

Comment: [DashO](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview) supports non-Android Java, on a variety of platforms, and has much stronger protection than ProGuard. (Full disclosure, I work for the company that makes DashO.)